# Docker: `exec format error` on `RUN apt update`

Tags: docker

This Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY . /srv/keller
WORKDIR /srv/keller
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
```

results in

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.167 MB
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> d9fad37da739
Step 1 : COPY . /srv/keller
 ---> 0691d53a9ddb
Removing intermediate container 76978e260250
Step 2 : WORKDIR /srv/keller
 ---> Running in 7d47ac19f397
 ---> 924513b02e82
Removing intermediate container 7d47ac19f397
Step 3 : RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
 ---> Running in 97284e8842bc
exec format error
[8] System error: exec format error
```

on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9. What is the problem here? Note that this is not about entrypoint/command. This error occurs on apt update.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an intel x86 64 image: `ubuntu:latest` on a raspberry pi (an ARM64), it cannot work out of the box...

Either you can change your base image to be compatible with your host (ex: `arm64v8/ubuntu`).

Or you can install qemu:

```
apt install -y qemu qemu-system-x86 binfmt-support qemu-user-static
```

and register it in docker:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while setting up pod in the cloud that runs Debian, while my machine is M1. I had to push some images to a private docker repo, but when I pushed them, I noticed the uploaded ones where not compatible with the architecture of the pod in the cluster.

My fix was pulling the correct image `docker pull --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9.16-buster` and then using that one istead of the pulled by just doing `docker pull --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9.16-buster`.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the export and a semi-colon, this should be

```
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get update
```

or you can use the && syntax

```
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update
```

Comment: `Step 3 : RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive &&  apt-get update
 ---> Running in 0f1bb3f3a051
exec format error`

Comment: `ENV_VAR=value some_command` is standard Bourne shell syntax to run the command with that environment variable set, but not to set it as a shell variable or export it for other later commands.